# Failure delivering result while picking image from camera but no issue when picking image from gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, onactivityresult, android-intent-chooser

i am developing an app in which there is a button which is used to pick image either from gallery or capture image from camera. When i pick an image from gallery there is no error image shows up fine in the end but when i capture image from my camera app crashes.

Following is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=66, result=-1, data=null} to activity 

{com.byteshaft.prospectform/com.byteshaft.prospectform.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4297)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4347)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.byteshaft.prospectform.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:400)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6926)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4293)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4347) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:173) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6459) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:938) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
```

My code for picking image from gallery/camera:

```
public void openImageIntent() {

        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String fname = "Prospect-form" + timeStamp;

        final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(storageDir, fname);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

        // Camera.
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }


        //Gallery.
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        // Filesystem.
        final Intent fsIntent = new Intent();
        fsIntent.setType("*/*");
        fsIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        cameraIntents.add(fsIntent);



        //Create the Chooser
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 66);
    }
```

**onActivityResult** code:`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            switch (requestCode){
                case 5:
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                        Bitmap resizedBitMap;
                        resizedBitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 100, 100, true);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitMap);
                        System.out.println(Helpers.getPath(MainActivity.this, selectedImage));
                        imagePath = Helpers.getPath(MainActivity.this, selectedImage);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "Some exception " + e);
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }`
```

There are some very useful answers on stackoverflow but i am unable to solve my problem. Only the error comes when i pick capture an image from camera otherwise there is no error at all when i choose image from gallery.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because picking an image from the camera and from the gallery don't return the same result. You have to check which one the user has chosen by looking at the intent. You can do it this way:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == mRequestCode) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                boolean isCamera = true;
                if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                    String action = data.getAction();
                    isCamera = MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.equals(action);
                }

                try {
                    Uri uriFileSrc = isCamera ? mOutputFileUri : data.getData();

                    //Do what do you need with the Uri

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, R.string.error_creating_file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } 
        }
}
```